# how to round half away from zero

Tags: java

I noticed that the definition of round half away from zero is: [image] I want all results to be rounded off to 3 decimal places, but I don't know how to compute it by java.

For example, 0.3333333 would be rounded to 0.333

Answer (score 3):

exactly like the mathematic definition:

```
((int) (-Math.sign(y) * Math.ceil(-Math.abs(y*1000) - 500))) / 1000.0
```

Comment: when I tried 0.333333, the result is 0.0 but I want 0.333

Comment: oh, i think i have the multiplication at the wrong position, I'll fix it

Comment: assuming the formula is correct, this should work now

Comment: Now I get 0.833 :)

Comment: its closer ;-) but this must be an issue with the formula now ...

Comment: you forgot to add the 500 back after doing the `ceil()`. the complete formula would be:
`((int) (-Math.signum(y) * (Math.ceil(-Math.abs(y*1000) - 500) + 500))) / 1000.0`